# my event dispatch run just one time when form is submit in svelte js, why?

Tags: javascript, vue.js, events, dispatch, svelte

My code is fetch data and put it in card ok, my event is when i add data in input move it to 
a fetching data in card, this is run just one more, when i add more, data added in database but it does not move in data list?
code is:

**Taskform.svelte**

```
<script>
    import { createEventDispatcher } from "svelte";

    let title = '';

    let dispatch = createEventDispatcher();

    function addTask(){
        axios.post('./api/tasks', {title: title});
        dispatch('taskCreated', {
            title: title,
        });
        title = '';
    }

</script>

<div class="row justify-content-center">
    <div class="col-md-8">
        <div class="card mt-2 bg-dark text-light">
            <div class="card-header">Create Task</div>

            <div class="card-body">
                <form action="./api/tasks" method="POST" on:submit|preventDefault={addTask}>
                    <div class="form-group">
                        <input type="text" name="title" placeholder="Task Title" class="form-control" bind:value={title}>
                    </div>
                    <div class="form-group">
                        <input type="submit" value="Add Task" class="btn btn-primary">
                    </div>
                </form>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

**Tasklist**

```
<script>
    import { onMount } from 'svelte';
    import Task from './Task.svelte';
    let tasks = [];

        onMount(async (event) => {
            axios.get('./api/tasks')
                .then((response) => {
                    tasks = response.data;
                });
        });

        function handler(event){
            tasks = [...tasks, {
                title: event.detail.title
            }];
        }    



</script>

<div class="row justify-content-center">
    <div class="col-md-8">
        <div class="card mt-2 bg-primary text-light">
            <div class="card-header">List Of Tasks</div>
            <div class="card-body">
                <ul>
                   <div class="row"> 
                        {#each tasks as task (task.id)}
                            <div class="col-3">
                                <li>{task.title}</li> 
                            </div>               
                        {/each} 
                    </div>
                </ul>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>

<Task on:taskCreated={handler}/>
```

please help i tried so many ways, nothing worked .
thanks

Answer (score 0):

Your dispatch is called as expected.
The issue is related to the lack of `id` in your tasks. If you'll add a unique `id` to each task it would all work (you can remove the `(task.id)` in your `#each` to verify).